# Creating node with prefix

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can i create a node like d2l_2p0:difficulty in xml file using asp.net

Comment: Look into creating xml documents with namespace. [This post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387075.aspx) has some good examples.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I build XmlDocument with many xml namespaces in a single node?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026570/how-can-i-build-xmldocument-with-many-xml-namespaces-in-a-single-node)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026570/how-can-i-build-xmldocument-with-many-xml-namespaces-in-a-single-node

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need to load an xml file that already exists from you file system, here is the easiest way to accomplish what your asking.

```
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(@"<The absolute path of your xml document>");
        XmlNode node = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;

        XmlElement element = xmlDoc.CreateElement("difficulty");
        element.Prefix = "d2I_2p0";
        node.AppendChild(element);

        xmlDoc.Save(@"<path you would like to save the file to>");
```